# Explicit isomorphism between a quartic extension of $\mathbb{F}_2$ and a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{F}_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I want to find an explicit isomorphism $\mathbb F _{2^4} \cong \mathbb F_{4^2}$, where $\mathbb{F}_{2^4}$ is a quartic extension of $\mathbb{F}_2$, and $\mathbb F_{4^2}$ is a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{F}_4$.

For sure it is $\mathbb F _{2^4} \cong \mathbb F_{4^2}$ by using the classification theorem of finitely generated Abelian groups.

My aim is, to construct $\mathbb F_2 [X] / (f)$ and $\mathbb F_4 [X] / (g)$ with irreducible polynomials $f \in \mathbb F_2 [X]$ and $g \in \mathbb F_4 [X]$ with degree 4, resp. 2, and to give a concrete ismorphism.

Comment: What do you even mean by $\Bbb F_{4^2}$?

Comment: I would say that $2^4=4^2\Longrightarrow\mathbb{F}_{2^4}=\mathbb{F}_{4^2}$.

Comment: $\mathbb F _{4^2}$ means $GF(4^2)$.

Comment: Obviously, ${\Bbb F}_{16} \cong {\Bbb F}_{16}$, but your last sentence is a real question. The point is to realize that all fields of 16 elements are isomorphic. Can you, for starters, find an irreducble $f$ of degree $4$ over ${\Bbb F}_2$?

Comment: $\operatorname{GF}(4^2) = \operatorname{GF}(16) = \operatorname{GF}(2^4)$ they're all the same isomorphism classes.

Comment: $f=X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$ is irreducible.

Comment: Nice, now you need to find an explicit representation of ${\Bbb F}_4$ as ${\Bbb F}_{2}[x]/(h)$ for some $h$ of degree $2$. There is only one choice for $h$, so that is easy, and this gives ${\Bbb F}_4 = {\Bbb F}_2[\alpha]$ with $\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1 = 0$. Next, can you find an irreducble $g$ of degree $2$ over ${\Bbb F}_4 = {\Bbb F}_2[\alpha]$? After that, ${\Bbb F}_2[x]/(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$ and ${\Bbb F}_4[x]/(g)$ must be isomorphic and to find an explicit isomorphism you need to find a root of $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ in ${\Bbb F}_4[x]/(g)$.

Comment: It has no roots in $\mathbb F_2$, so the only possibility to factorize it is into two polynomials with degree 2. Choose $(X^2+aX+c)(X^2+dX+b)=X^4+(a+d)X^3+(b+c+ad)X^2+(cd+ab)X+bc$. So $bc=1$ leads to $b=c=1$. $a+d=1$ leads to $a=1$ and $d=0$ or $d=1$ and $a=0$. But $(b+c+ad)=1$ leads to $ad=1$, which contradicts.

Comment: Well, I can choose $g=X^2+X+1$. It is irreducible, because it has no roots in $\mathbb F_4$. $g(0)=1,g(1)=3,g(2)=3,g(3)=1$

Comment: No, $g$ has a root in ${\Bbb F}_4 = {\Bbb F}[\alpha]$, namely $\alpha$.

Comment: And note that ${\Bbb F}_4 \neq {\Bbb Z}/4$.

Comment: I think there is nothing to add to José Carlos Santos's comment.

Comment: @Magdiragdag I chose $g=X^2+\alpha X+1$, which is irreducible in $\mathbb F _2 [\alpha]$, because $g(0)=1,g(1)=\alpha,g(\alpha)=1,g(\alpha+1)=1$.
You said, that I can find the explicite isomorphism with a root of $f$ in $\mathbb F_4 [X] /(g)$. But how does this isomorphism look like, if I got this root?

Comment: Once you have the root, the isomorphism ${\Bbb F}_2[x]/(f) \to {\Bbb F}_4[x]/(g)$ maps (the residue class of) $x$ to that root.

Comment: OP, I edited your post to make the question clearer.  Feel free to rollback or edit it yourself if you don't like my changes.

Answer (score 1):

Finding $f$ is easy. Just factor $x^{16}-x \bmod 2$ and take any factor of degree $4$:
$$
x^{16}-x =
x (x + 1) (x^2 + x + 1) (x^4 + x + 1) (x^4 + x^3 + 1) (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)
$$

Comment: Why I can choose $X^{16}-X$ ?

Comment: @MyrkulsJayKay, because all elements in a finite field of order $q$ are roots of $X^q-X$. This is a consequence of Lagrange's theorem of group theory.